# Retrieve the complete certificate chain from Java Truststore given the RootCA certificate or child certificate as input

Tags: java, cryptography, certificate, bouncycastle, truststore

I have a **Java truststore foo.p12** which contains multiple public certificates such as RootCA certificates, Intermediate RootCA certificates signed by its RootCA, end entity server certificates issued by Intermediate RootCA (For example foo.p12 contains RootCA_1, IntermediateCA_1, EndEntity_1, RootCA_2, IntermediateCA_2, EndEntity_2).

I have a requirement, given the rootca_1 or EndEntity_1 as input, I need to read foo.p12 and retrieve all the certificate chain corresponding to rootca_1 or EndEntity_1.

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097375/obtaining-the-certificate-chain) link which has similar question, but the answers are not updated and also it does not give the solution to my problem. There is another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508050/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-trusted-root-certificates-in-java), but this again returns all the certificates under foo.p12 but not the certificate chains as I require.

Is there any Java solutions (JCE API's or Bouncy Castle API's etc) which could return the certificate chain given the rootCA or end entity certificate?

Comment: Why? Truststores don't contain chains, they just contain individual certificates, and your requirement to start from a given root could yield a tree, not a single chain. It is up to the person who provides you with an end certificate to provide enough of the chain to reach a root that is in your truststore. Not the other way round. Something seriously wrong here.

Comment: Yes, my truststore contains only individual public certificates. Now for given rootCA_1, I need to find that tree structure and retrieve that specific tree. I can build my own logic to loop through each certificate entry in the trust store to identify and  construct that tree structure. But before doing that, I want to check and utilize any Java API/utility that provides such implementation already. Given an input RootCA, I want to identify and retrieve only its related children certificates using existing Java API's (if any)

Comment: This an unusual requirement, so naturally there is nothing in the Java SE to perform this. You'll have to write your own code. Typically a truststore contains only root certificates, not intermediate or end-entity certificates. The whole point of this model is that you need only trust one or a few root certificates. If you directly trust an intermediate cert then there's no point in trusting its ancestor certs. Thus, if you trust an end-entity cert then there's no point in trusting any other cert.